# Asp.net Auto-increment data (That comes from database) to a variable -Error Object Cannot be cast from DBNull

Tags: c#, asp.net

It keeps appearing this error `"Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types."` 
on `totaldevotos += Convert.ToInt32(dr["Classificacao"])`,

im trying to convert the object that comes from the database `"Classificacao"` into a `Integer`, (its a Int field on the Database), any ideas?

```
string sql = "SELECT * from Users LEFT JOIN Cocktails on Users.ID_Utilizador=Cocktails.ID_utilizador1 LEFT JOIN Rating on Cocktails.ID_cocktail=Rating.ID_cocktail WHERE Cocktails.ID_utilizador1=Users.ID_utilizador AND Users.ID_utilizador=" + ID;
int totaldevotos = 0;
SqlDataReader dr = con.query(sql);
while (dr.Read())
{
    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        totaldevotos += Convert.ToInt32(dr["Classificacao"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: either check if the`dr["Classificacao"] is null using the string.IsNullOrEmpty` function or I would suggest altering your Sql statement and in the Where clause adding `AND Classificacao IS NOT NULL`

Comment: try something like this .. 
`totaldevotos += dr["Classificacao"].IsDbNull ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(dr["Classificacao"]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in the database is NULL for at least some rows.

Before you try to parse the value, check to see if it's null.

```
if (dr.HasRows)
{
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        if (dr["Classificacao"] != DBNull.Value)
        {
            totaldevotos += Convert.ToInt32(dr["Classificacao"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you only need to check `dr.HasRows` once, before you start the loop.

Comment: it's not if it has rows.. its the fact that you cannot convert a DBNull.Value to an Int.. tenary would actually work to set the value if null to 0  else...etc..